# When graphing both X, and Y are fractions

Tags: graphing-functions, fractions

In my instructions, I am told to place the point on the coordinate system. My X, and Y value are

### $$(\frac 52, \frac 72)$$

at this point I am a little lost. Would I flip it, and multiply it like so?

$$ \frac 25 * \frac 52 $$ $$ \frac 27 * \frac 72 $$

then reduce down and have my results being (1,1)?

edit; my question is, what method would I use to get rid of the fractions, and be given whole number, but user41736 showed me simply dividing the fraction is the correct method to use to get the whole number.

Comment: $x=2.5$ and $y=3.5$. They lie between 2,3 and 3,4 respectively.

Comment: @SS_C4 andyADD cannot find those points in the system.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking, to be honest...

Comment: @user41736, Oh, ok then

Comment: question edit. thank you user41736 I guess I was just overthinking it.

Comment: I saw your edit and have a comment: $2.5$ and $3.5$ are not whole numbers. Actually $\frac{5}{2}$ and $2.5$ are the *same number* written in two different ways. $\frac{5}{2} = 2.5$ You can check this on a calculator. Similarly, $\frac{7}{2} = 3.5$.

Comment: My fault, i generally meant make them into non fractions (whether whole or decimal number) to make it easier to graph.

Answer (score 0):

To plot the point $(5/2, 7/2)$, observe that $5/2 = 2.5$ and $7/2 = 3.5$.  Thus, the $x$-coordinate of the point is halfway between $2$ and $3$ and the $y$-coordinate of the point is halfway between $3$ and $4$.  Therefore, we obtain

[image: plotting_point_with_rational_coordinates]